# Azure DevOps Conditional for Multiple values

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have been following [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-in-pipelines) and created a release pipeline in YAML, all works fine.

I have a conditional step that works fine as well:

```
- ${{ if contains(parameters.environment, 'PROD') }}:
```

Now requirement changed a bit, and the same conditional step requires checking against multiple values.

For if this contains PROD or UAT is true.

I have been reading different places and tried the following without luck:

```
- ${{ or(if contains(parameters.environment, 'PROD'), if contains(parameters.environment, 'UAT')) }}:

- ${{ if contains(parameters.environment, 'PROD', 'UAT') }}:
```

Any idea if this is possible and how to solve it? much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take for example the below:

```
${{ if or( eq(parameters.environment, 'PROD'), eq(parameters.environment, 'UAT') ) }}:
```

**expressions syntax:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions

Comment: Thanks for this answer, helped me save lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `in` operator which makes it more concise IMO, like so:

```
${{ if in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual', 'PullRequest') }}
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#in

Comment: 'Evaluates True if left parameter is equal to any right parameter' not the same as contains. (string exists in string)